# How to get Windows version number (e.g. 1903 or 1909) on the command line?

Tags: windows

I want exactly the same output as `winver` only on the command line. For example, on my machine running `winver` returns this:

[image]

I need a command line alternative that would return 1909. I know how to get the 18363 piece - `[environment]::OSVersion.Version.Build` (in powershell). Googling reveals several options, none of which tell me that the version is 1909:

- `wmic os get`
- `systeminfo`

Now maybe they encode it differently, I do not know. Ideally I want to get the Version and the OS Build.

**EDIT 1**

I am OK to read it from registry, since it can be done on the command line.

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to a hint from [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv) I found it:

```
(get-itemproperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseId).ReleaseId
```

Comment: Don't know that there is an API for that besides reading it from the registry directly, and things don't seem to have changed since [Retrieving Windows version “1511”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641076/retrieving-windows-version-1511).

Comment: @dxiv If you provide an answer, I would be able to credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "*Version*" number displayed in `winver` matches the `ReleaseID` value from the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, and circumstantial evidence suggests that there is no API to retrieve it, other than reading it from the registry (per my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704910/5538420)).

The following reads the version number from the registry into a `Version` environment variable at the `cmd` prompt (double the `%%a`, `%%c` percents when using in a batch file).

```
C:\etc>for /f "tokens=1-3" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseID') do @set "Version=%~c"

C:\etc>echo Version = '%Version%'
Version = '2004'
```